# グーグルフォーム自動返信で「受信者が指定されていません」というエラー

Tags: google-apps-script

初めて新規事業のHPを開設して、色々なサイトを見てグーグルフォームの自動返信に１度（練習用に作った本番をコピーしたグーグルフォーム）成功したのですが、いざそのスクリプトをコピーして本番のサイトで試したところトリガーのエラー率が１００％（涙）＊相手に送信出来ていません。

何をやっても

```
メールを送信できませんでした: 受信者が指定されていません at auto_reply(コード:53)や（５５）
```

と出るばかりです。

同じコピペした原本を再度やっても結果は同じ（涙）
どのように解決したら宜しいでしょうか？
またどこか良いサイト等があったら是非教えて頂きたいです。
素人質問で申し訳ありませんがご回答宜しくお願い致します。

```
function auto_reply() {
    //自動返信メールの件名
    var title = "【コピーにご登録ありがとうございます】"; 

    //自動返信メールの本文1(\nは改行)
    var body
    = "『居場所や』へのご依頼やご相談は\n"
    + "24時間いつでも受け付けております！\n"


    + "何かございましたらこちらまで宜しくお願い致します！\n"
    + "https://forms.gle/7p4RsNvdp7xCj361A\n"
    + "------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"

    //自動返信メールの本文2(\nは改行)
    var body2
    = "------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
    + "内容を確認の上、あらためてご連絡させていただきます。\n";
    + "本メールに心当たりが無い場合は、その旨を記載の上ご返信下さいますようお願い申し上げます。\n\n";


    //本文作成用の変数
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = sheet.getLastRow();
    var column = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();

    //メールアドレス保存用の変数(最後のメール送信時に使用。)
    var  mail = "";

    for (var i = 1; i <= column; i++ ) {
        //スプレッドシートの入力項目名を取得
        var header = range.getCell(1, i).getValue(); 
        //スプレッドシートの入力値を取得
        var value = range.getCell(row, i).getValue();

        //本文1(body)にスプレッドシートの入力項目を追加
        body += "■"+header+"\n";

        //本文1(body)にフォームの入力内容を追加
        body += value + "\n\n";

        //スプレッドシートの入力項目が「お名前」の場合は、「様」を付け本文の前に追加
        if ( header === 'お名前' ) {
            body = value+" 様\n\n"+body;
        }

        //フォームの入力項目が「メールアドレス」の場合は、変数mailに代入
        if ( header === 'メールアドレス' ) {
            mail = value;
        }
    }
    //本文1に本文2を追加
    body += body2;

    //宛名＝mail、件名＝title、本文=bodyで、メールを送る
    GmailApp.sendEmail(mail,title,body);
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは重要な情報が乗っている場合があり、明確にコピペ追記していただいてもよろしいですか？複数表示される場合は複数とも追記いただけるとより回答が付きやすいでしょう。

Comment: トリガではなく、関数を直接実行することは可能ですか？（手で実行する場合に権限の付与確認が発生し、これを行わないと実行できない場合が多いです）